# How to consume restTemplate response when response body is different on different status code

Tags: java, spring-resttemplate, response-entity

While calling the api, the response I get is either json object or array of string on basis of different status code. How do I consume this using restTemplate

Comment: Please, take some time to read [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example)